# Manage Groups filters broken in 4.7.7?

Tags: groups, 4.7, smartgroups

I'm running 4.7.7 in Word Press and none of the filters on the Manage Groups page seem to be working. It's been replicated by other users so it doesn't seem to be an issue related to users and/or local machines. Is this happening to others?

Edit: I've been digging around further, is there a chance that this is related to CRM-18528? I've applied the new code and it seems to be working, although from what I've seen this applies to the Drupal version. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to a wider audience!  I just confirmed the issue on the demo site, which is the first step toward determining if this is a bug for everyone (see [Reporting a Bug](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting)).

I've confirmed it's not an AJAX error or a problem with how the URL is constructed, which were my first guesses.  I'll take a few minutes to poke around in the code, and if the problem's not obvious I'll report it upstream at https://issues.civicrm.org.

UPDATE: The problem's not obvious to me, but I know there are some bugfixes in process for this set of new functionality ([CRM-16353](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16353))